# WiFiDirectDevice::FromIdAsync throws in Win32 Console App

Tags: windows-runtime, wifi-direct, c++-cx

I'm trying to use WiFiDirect API from Windows 10 SDK and implement the Connector scenario in Win32 Console App. I've already enabled C++/CX in basic Console app and integrated code from [Microsoft's example on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WiFiDirect/cpp).

For now I can successfully discover devices and even connect and transfer data if the devices are already paired. But when I'm trying to pair them from scratch, FromIdAsync task ends up as Cancelled and the last line below throws an exception saying that **"The remote procedure call failed."**

```
        WiFiDirectConnectionParameters^ connectionParams = ref new WiFiDirectConnectionParameters();
        connectionParams->GroupOwnerIntent = (short)(wcstoul(txtGOIntent->Text->Data(), nullptr, 10));

        // IMPORTANT: FromIdAsync needs to be called from the UI thread
        concurrency::task<WiFiDirectDevice^> fromIdTask(WiFiDirectDevice::FromIdAsync(discoveredDevice->DeviceInfo->Id, connectionParams));
        fromIdTask.then([this](concurrency::task<WiFiDirectDevice^> fromIdResultTask)
        {
            try
            {
                WiFiDirectDevice^ wfdDevice = fromIdResultTask.get();
```

I believe that it cannot show the popup with PIN entry, but how to overcome this?

Comment: It is documented, `[MarshalingBehavior(Agile)]` means that you can't call it from a console mode app.  Nothing "agile" about it.

Comment: @HansPassant This makes WiFi Direct totally unusable from Desktop app. Can I do something about it? I don't know, maybe create UI thread from my app or some other trick?

Comment: Pretty obscure, I'm guessing you need to decorate main() with [Platform::STAThread] as mentioned in [this web page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications).  Never tried it.  Keep in mind that nothing pretty will happen if it ever decides to display a popup, ought to deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[update] TH2 has been out for a while, so the [custom device pairing API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformationcustompairing) is what I was alluding to originally.  There is a [SDK sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) as well that shows you how to do use it.  Checkout scenario 9 in the sample.

To be clear, you can pair a device in an app in 3-4 ways:

1. Using the device picker control, it can pair devices inline
2. Use the simple pairing API.  As mentioned, it has to be called on the apps UI thread because the shell may not be able to figure out where to draw the app modal dialog otherwise
3. Use the custom device pairing API
4. Use the inbound pairing API (only applicable to Bluetooth on IoT devices)

Most of the APIs in Windows.Devices.Enumeration* are considered "dual" APIs meaning they work in an app container as well as in a medium IL win32 type process.  The exceptions are APIs that generate UI (ie. #1, & #2), so in your scenario, only #3 will work in a desktop console app.

Before TH2, #2 from above would implicitly happen.  The RPC call fails because a console app is not in an app container, so the shell can't inject a modal dialog.

[original response] Obviously this is a scenario that should work.  You should look for better support for win32 app using WiFiDirect WinRT APIs in [Threshold 2](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/81925/20150905/microsoft-s-next-windows-10-automatic-update-threshold-2-delayed-until-november.htm) which soon to be released to everyone.  You can try it now with a flighted insider build of Windows 10.  I think the scenario in your question should be working.

I recommend checking out the TH2 SDK whenever it comes out.  Check to see if there are new APIs that can solve your problems.  Ping me after it ships, and I can give you more details on how to manage WFD pairing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem doing the exact same thing, but in C# instead of C++. The lack of documentation about `WiFiDirectDevice` is mildly infuriating, but I found something similar [in a relatively similar class remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.hiddevice.fromidasync.aspx), saying that `FromIdAsync` needs to be called from a UI thread in order to display the consent prompt (as you and I suspected).

For some reason Microsoft thought that it was a good idea to force developers to depend on an specific UI framework in order to use WiFiDirect. However, this seems to be mandatory only the first time, because as you already achieved, once the two devices trust each other is possible to connect through a command line application. So maybe a "connect two devices" simple application can get the work done.

Testing this behavior is proving to be a difficult: trusted devices are listed under `Settings > Privacy > Other devices`, but unchecking the other computer only makes the application attempting the connection (not the one advertising it) fail, not ask for permission again, and there's not such thing as "forget this device" in order to show the consent prompt again.

Edit: it seems that if you delete one device from the other using Devices and Printers menu in the Control Panel, you must do exactly the same on the other computer or you'll get the descriptive exception `Element not found` while executing `FromIdAsync` on the advertiser machine.

Edit 2: running the `FromIdAsync` on the UI thread of a WPF application doesn't work either (reuslting again in the `Remote procedure call failed` exception), which makes me think that it tries to invoke some *Store* specific function not available to other kind of applications. It's really sad that Microsoft ties such an amazing feature as WiFiDirect to their Universal Application Platform like this.

Edit 3: I see you marked the other answer as correct. Could you share the solution that Windows 10 Threshold 2 seems to offer? I could not find a workaround yet.

Comment: Are you saying that it can be done from some sort of specific WinRT UI thread only and there is no way to get it in Desktop app?

Comment: Btw, device can be easily "forgotten" from Devices and Printer menu in Control Panel by clicking Remove device

Comment: @Yrchgrchh WiFiDirect Services, which is new in Windows 10 (and lets you advertise one or more different services in a single machine) allows you to modify authentication method (for example letting you set a specific pin that could be hardcoded both sides, or even without pin), but `WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync` **needs** to run from the UI thread https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/WiFiDirect/cs/Scenario1_Advertiser.xaml.cs#L211

Comment: @Yrchgrchh btw, I erased the other device form Devices and Printers, but it still shows up in Settings > Privacy > Other Devices :(

Comment: @Yrchgrchh I found a class named [DeviceInformationPairing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt168401.aspx) with a method named `PairAsync` in which you can set a protection level, which could get PIN identification away. I don't add it as answer because I couldn't get it to work. There's a [UWP sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumeration) where this is used from client side, but not a clue about how the advertiser in the GO side should be started... let me know if you accomplish something with this!

Comment: Thanks for the info, I believe it doesn't work because this API is not available in Desktop apps (doesn't have DualApiPartition attribute), but anyway it seems like there is no way you can establish WiFi Direct connection without popups (pin, push button, nfc) as it's required by WPS. I'm just wondering what is the purpose of exposing API to Desktop if no one can actually use it.

Comment: The UI thread requirement has more to do with the shell (system UX) being able to correctly identify where to put the pairing dialog.  With out it, there are some cases where the pop up might not be visible.  Obviously that would be a bad experience.